# Reading variables from config file in Shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, variables

I have question about Linux shell scripts. My question is realy abstract, so may not make sense. The idea is having 1 script and 2 config files.

Script can be like (drinkOutput.sh):

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -e " $1 \n"
echo -e " $2 \n"
```

First Config file contain (beer.conf):

```
drink1="heineken"
drink2="argus"
```

Second Config file contain (vine.conf):

```
drink1="chardonnay"
drink2="hibernal"
```

The key thing is calling the script. It has to be in next format (or with parameter)

```
./drinkOutput.sh beer.conf
```

In this case I need to have in $1 heineken and in $2 argus (inside of drinkOutput script). For

```
./drinkOutput.sh vine.conf
```

I need to get back into drinkOutput.sh chardonnay and hibernal.

Does anybody know? Thanks for any tips

Comment: You can't. `$<number>` is always `argument number <number>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `source` the config files if they are in the right format (and it seems it is in your example).

```
drinkOutput()
{
    echo "$1"
    echo "$2"
}

conf="$1"
source "$conf"
drinkOutput "$drink1" "$drink2"
```

Comment: The only thing I'd add is a check that the conf file exists: `[[ -f "$conf" ]] || exit 1`

Comment: If for whatever reason you really need `$1` and `$2` to be the two beverages, just add `set -- "$drink1" "$drink2"` following the `source` command.

Answer (score 0):

If is possible if your script calls itself with the proper arguments after having parsed them from the conf file:

```
if [ $# == 2 ] ; then
   # The arguments are correctly set in the sub-shell.
   # 2 arguments: do something with them
   echo magic happens: $1 $2

elif [ $# == 1 ] ; then
   # 1 argument: conf file: parse conf file
   arg1=`sed -n -e 's#drink1="\(.*\)"#\1#p' $1`
   arg2=`sed -n -e 's#drink2="\(.*\)"#\1#p' $1`
   $0 $arg1 $arg2
else
    # error
    echo "wrong args"
fi
```

test:

```
$ drinkOutput.sh beer.conf
magic happens: heineken argus
```